# Is there an Adobe AIR like product for just HTML5 (no flash) on Windows

Tags: windows, html, webkit, tidesdk

I would like to create a Windows desktop app using HTML5 features, specifically H.264 video,Web SQL Database,FileReader API. I don't want to use AIR (which currently does not support the video tag, instead uses Flash). Ideally I would like an exe file that just wraps the latest version of webkit in a basic window. It should be stand alone, not rely on the user having Chrome etc. installed. It could load an index.html file in the same directory as the exe. That is it.

I have been unable to find anything like this. I was going to build it myself using QTWebkit but the latest version (4.8.0) does not support the Video tag due to some kind of build issue. I assume the 4.8.1 version will fix this.
Does anyone out there know of something like this that is available now?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this, Titanium for desktop is no longer supported by Appcelerator, *but* the project is still supported as an open source initiative. As of today (10/14/2012), it is called [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org). According to their Twitter account, they're behind in the 1.3 release due to some sponsored work that will end up in the code base.

Additional options not yet mentioned include [AppJS](http://appjs.org) (OSS, requires node.js) and [Sencha Desktop Packager](http://docs.sencha.com/desktop-packager/1-0/#!/guide/getting_started) (quite pricey).

Answer (score 2):

I think titanium is not totally gone. There is this stuff called [tideSdk](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#)
I couldn't try it out yet also , so video support and the codec are open for your exploration. Here is how they say:

> Create multi-platform desktop apps with HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript
>   TideSDK is the new standard for creating beautiful and unique desktop
>   apps using your web development skills.

Answer (score 2):

I recently thought about doing the same thing, you can still do it with air without using flash, but you could also use Chrome Packaged apps, mozilla prism (although inactive today) or Microsoft HTA (html application).

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using a framework that does the browser embedding for you like [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/showcase/applications-showcase/).  It's mostly used for creating apps that can be published to iphone, android, and windows devices.  It will create a windows MSI install.

Another option is to use the [CEF project](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) ( Chromium Embedded Framework for C/C++).  I havn't looked at it much, so I can't tell you how difficult/easy it is to work with.  Their main site also has wrappers for Java, .NET, and other languages.

Comment: Unfortunately Titanium on the desktop is no longer supported. CEF looks good but doesn't support h.264, probably a licensing issue I would guess. Works well with webM and Ogg though.